# Reduce file size of matplotlib images in jupyter notebooks?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter

I often work with complex matplotlib figures with millions of points, which I've been displaying in my notebooks using the ipython magic `%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'`. Unfortunately, these inline images are quite large in terms of file size.

I'm looking for general suggestions on how to reduce the size of my ipynb files, which can grow into the 10s or even hundreds of MB in size and become a bit unwieldy.

One thought I had was to switch to generating jpegs, but while it looks like I can  meaningfully reduce the file size by switching the backend to jpeg and increasing the dpi to 2x:

```py
from matplotlib import rcParams
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'jpeg'
rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 200
```

I can't figure out how to size them appropriately for a retina display (they're twice as large as they should be, and slightly blurry). Is there a way to display jpegs in jupyter notebooks at similar resolution and size to the defaults provided by `'retina'` mode?

Comment: Do you want to keep the figures in the files ?  If not, you could just strip them out with extensions. It may be a bug if "retina jpeg" are not the right size. Feel free to open a bug on GitHub.

Comment: @matt - good question. I (a) do want to keep the images in the notebook and (b) `"retina"` goes in the same place `"jpeg"` goes so there isn't a way to specify `"retina jpeg"`. I'll open an issue on mpl's github

Comment: Thanks, there might be issues in multiple repositories involved to understand "retina" and "jpg" at the same time.